# Angular 16 standalone component won't render when used in another standalone component

Tags: angular

I created 2 standalone components and am attempting to use one inside the other.  When looking at the `Elements` tab in the inspector I can see the component is rendered in the `HTML` and even contains the data being passed into it through an `@Input` however the component doesn't render on the screen.

This is what my parent component's decorator looks like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sidebar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, LinkComponent],
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
```

As you can see in the `imports` array I'm importing a `LinkComponent` which looks like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'link',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './link.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./link.component.css']
})
```

Inside the `sidebar` component's template I initially used the `link` component like this

```
<section class="linkContainer">
    <link *ngFor="let link of Links" [Link]="link" />
</section>
```

As I mentioned I can see each `link` component in the `ELements` tab but nothing shows up on the screen.  I tried adding a closing tag to make it `<link></link>` but `VSCode` kept auto-completing the parent `<section>` tag after I pushed the `/` key.  After a bit of frustration I went outside of the top level element and typed it and got the following error.

> Void elements do not have end tags "link"

I have no clue as to what makes my component a `void element` or how to change it.  Does anybody know why this is happening?  Other than that all my code is functioning as expected but for the sake of showing what I'm doing incase the problem rests somewhere else here's all my code.

***SidebarComponent***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sidebar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, LinkComponent],
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit{
  Links!: Link[];

  constructor(private linkService: SidebarService){
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.loadLinks();
  }

  private loadLinks(): void{
    this.Links = this.linkService.getLinks();
    console.log(this.Links);
  }

}
```

***SidebarComponent template***

```
<nav class="mainContainer">

    <svg class="closeButton" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20px" height="20px">
        <use href="#close_button" fill="hsl(var(--gray-400))" />
    </svg>

    

    <section class="linkContainer">
        <link *ngFor="let link of Links" [Link]="link" />
    </section>

</nav>
```

***SidebarService***

```
export const LINKS: Link[] = [
  {
    id: 'introduction',
    title: 'Introduction',
    path: 'home'
  },
  {
    id: 'gettingStarted',
    title: 'Getting Started',
    path: 'getting-started'
  },
  {
    id: 'libraries',
    title: 'Libraries',
    path: 'libraries',
    subLinks: [
      {
        id: 'boxSize',
        title: 'Box Size Library',
        path: 'box-size-library'
      },
      {
        id: 'textSize',
        title: 'Text Size Library',
        path: 'text-size-library'
      },
      {
        id: 'lineSize',
        title: 'Line Size Library',
        path: 'line-size-library'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'classes',
    title: 'Classes',
    path: 'classes',
    subLinks: [
      {
        id: 'srcryBox',
        title: 'Srcry Box Class',
        path: 'srcry-box-class'
      },
      {
        id: 'srcryTxt',
        title: 'Srcry Text Class',
        path: 'srcry-text'
      }
    ]
  }
]

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SidebarService {

  Links : Link[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.loadLinks();
  }

  private loadLinks(): void{
    this.Links = LINKS;
  }

  public getLinks(): Link[]{
    return this.Links;
  }
}
```

***LinkComponent***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'link',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './link.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./link.component.css']
})
export class LinkComponent {
  @Input() Link!: Link;
  @Output() Selection: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  public updatePage(path: string): void{ this.Selection.emit(path); }

}
```

***LinkComponent template***

```
<section>
    <article>
        <p>{{Link.title}}</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

Does anybody see the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Change selector in your LinkComponent from link to app-link `app` is prefix for your application in `angular.json` file:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-link',
   standalone: true,
   imports: [CommonModule],
   templateUrl: './link.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./link.component.css']
})
export class LinkComponent {
   @Input() Link!: Link;
   @Output() Selection: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

   public updatePage(path: string): void{ this.Selection.emit(path); }

}
```

and use it in SidebarComponent template as follows:

```
<nav class="mainContainer">
  <svg class="closeButton" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20px" height="20px">
    <use href="#close_button" fill="hsl(var(--gray-400))" />
  </svg>
  <section class="linkContainer">
    <app-link *ngFor="let link of Links" [Link]="link" />
  </section>
</nav>
```

`<link></link>` is HTML Tag thats why is not working for you. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp